# Pinescript (Tradingview) stop and limit not working every time

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

```
longcon = crossover(ema5, ema21)
longCondition1 = longcon[4]
longCondition2 = ema50 > ema200 ? 1: 0
longCondition3 = bbr > 0.75 ? 1: 0
longCondition4 = sig > 15 ? 1: 0
longCondition5 = ao > 2 ? 1: 0
if (longCondition1 and longCondition2 and longCondition3 and longCondition4 and longCondition5)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price*0.98, limit=strategy.position_avg_price*1.01)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price*0.98)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price*1.01)
```

I have been trying to backtest this strategy but for some reason, the Stop Loss and Take Proft (Limit) do not work properly and I have no idea why. I plotted those values and the script just does not execute when those levels are reached.
[image]

You can see the first exit is incorrect as the price increased by 1% but the script did not sell. The second time around the script works fine. What causes this?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:

```
if (longCondition1 and longCondition2 and longCondition3 and longCondition4 and longCondition5)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price*0.98, limit=strategy.position_avg_price*1.01)
```